# Crunchy vs Chewy dried apples?

Tags: dehydrating

When making dried apples, how does one control for whether the apples come out crunchy or chewy? Is it a matter of equipment (eg: dehydrator vs oven vs sun dried), the type of apples, additives, something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just how long you dry them.  Thin apple slices work best for crunchy chips and then just dry them till they're crunchy - sometimes as much as 18-20 hours.  Soft, chewy dehydrated apples just go for a shorter time.